# use the R documentation over a local webserver

Tags: r

When I use R on Windows (inside Rgui) and type `?table` a browser window opens and show me the documentation about `table`. This work local without internet connection.

When I do this on `Debian unstable` in `R` the help text is displayed inside the R console. I want it the windows way here but don't know how to set this up or if this is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `~/.Rprofile` file:

```
options("help_type"="html")
```

Also see `?utils::help`:

> help_type: character string: the type of help required.  Possible
>             values are ‘"text"’, ‘"html"’ and ‘"pdf"’.  Case is ignored,
>             and partial matching is allowed.